# Queuing PHP scripts in RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am trying to use RabbitMQ in PHP to run about 40 scripts consecutively. What I've got so far is sort of working, but not quite as I want it to.

One PHP script (which will ultimately be scheduled to run nightly) sends a series of messages to the queue, as below:

```
php public_html/worker/mis-update-school.php 9195408 1
php public_html/worker/mis-update-school.php 8954001 1
php public_html/worker/mis-update-school.php 3424051 1
```

These are then received by the consumer and executed like so:

```
public function action($msg)
        {
            $message = $msg->body ;

            shell_exec($message);
        }
```

This appears to work, as in it is waiting for each script to complete before the next one begins. However, this seems to be PHP that's doing that, rather than RabbitMQ. All of the Rabbit MQ messages seem to get consumed at the same time.

How can I tell RabbitMQ to wait until the `shell_exec()` has completed before processing the next message?

The reason this is important is that during busy periods, I would like to be able to add more dynos to the queue to run more than one of the scripts at once. At present, that's not possible because all of the scripts are pulled from the queue immediately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have solved this myself by simply adding a line after the `shell_exec()` in the `action($msg)` function.

```
public function action($msg)
        {
            $message = $msg->body ;

            shell_exec($message);

            send_remote_syslog("Job complete: $message", "mis-update-queue");

        }
```

I'd be interested to know why this is the case...